# Mark.js cannot remove words in the middle

Tags: vue.js, mark.js

Requirement: Highlight specific words in a PDF document based on the backend response. Currently, this functionality is already implemented, but the PDF may contain page numbers, tables, or charts, which results in the PDF document being loaded multiple times during the keyword extraction process. I'm not sure where the problem lies, but visually, it appears that when a particular segment is highlighted, the view keeps returning to the top, then suddenly jumps back to the intended highlighted position. Can you please advise on how to solve this issue? Should I adjust a specific configuration in mark.js?

eg:

```js
const markSearch = (value: string) => {
  // console.log({ markSearch: value })
  const context: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('#viewerContainer')
  if (markInstance) {
    markInstance.unmark()
  }
  const instance = new Mark(context)
  console.log('instance :>> ', instance)
  // let pagesResult = new Array(pdfViewer._pages.length).fill(0)
  instance.mark(value, {
    acrossElements: true,  
    ignoreJoiners: true,  
    ignorePunctuation: [' ', ','],   
    separateWordSearch: false, 
    accuracy: 'partially', //  
    wildcards: 'withSpaces', //  "disabled"、"enabled"   "withSpaces"。
    noMatch: async (e) => {
      console.log(e, '-----------------------------')
      // console.log('noMatch')
      const total = pdfViewer._pages.length
      const current = pdfViewer.currentPageNumber
      // console.log(current, total)
      if (current !== total) {
        pdfViewer.nextPage()
        console.log('current !== total :>> ', current !== total)
        await sleep(200)
        markSearch(e)
      } else {
        pdfViewer.currentPageNumber = 1
        return
      }
    },
    done: (marksTotal: number) => {
      // console.log(marksTotal)
      // console.log('done')
      // console.log(element)
      if (marksTotal > 0) {
        const element = document.querySelector('mark')
        element &&
          element.scrollIntoView({
            block: 'start'
            // behavior: 'smooth'
          })
      }
    },
    each: (element: Element) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        element.classList.add('animate')
      }, 100)
    }
  })
  markInstance = instance
}
```